# ReSharper Code Snippet for Auto-Property

Tags: c#, resharper-4.5

Is there a way to create an auto property via code snippet using ReSharper?  Like the prop for VS?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is wrong with just using the VS one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resharper 5 has a prop snippet which goes to auto-property.  Does 4.5 not?

Comment: It absolutely does. Generate Property allows the user to select which form, autoprop, prop with backing field or "throw new NotImplementedException()".

Comment: but how do I do this via keyboard with R#?

Comment: I know about Alt + Ins, is that what you're talking about?  But I can't get to properties if I have no backing fields defined in that context menu.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Just put your cursor where you want the property and type prop<Tab> (you can probably get away with just typing pr<Tab>)

Comment: I see no prop snippet when I do a Ctrl + J in 4.5

Comment: lol, I guess I was thinking the prop was the VS prop.  duh, it does give you an automatic property.  It must be using R#?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm never sure which app is doing what, it's been so long since I worked without R#. I know if I type prop, I get an auto-property; that's all I need to know. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a [Live Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html#Live_Templates)

Just go to the Resharper menu, and choos Live Templates. Click the little green + icon and add this:

```
public $type$ $name$ { get; set; }
```

Then give the wanted shortcut, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can setup any snippet you wish.  These are called "Live Templates" in Resharper, and have a lot more functionality than the VS versions.  Just choose "Resharper->Live Templates.." in VS to edit them.